# Python while loop does not return result

Tags: python

I have the following list and when I run while loop, it just print the first name in the list.
As you can see the db_name list is in 1 column.

```
db_name
testdb1
testdb2
testdb3
testdb4
.
.
.
```

My code:

```
i=0
while i < len(db_name):
         print(db_name)
         i += 1
```

Comment: Your code prints the same thing every loop. What do you want it to print?

Comment: is `db_name` and pandas series or a list? Not that it matters much but just for clarification

Comment: What you show as a "list" is not a Python list. Please show us a real list, one that you use or a shorter one. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I want to connect to every database: dbconn=os.popen(f"""db2 connect to {db_name}[i]""").read()

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in db_name:
    print(item)
```

That's the pythonic way of printing a list.

To do what you're trying to do:

```
for item in db_name:
    dbconn=os.popen("db2 connect to {}".format(item)).read()
```

Comment: do **not** use list comprehensions for side-effects (like printing). That is an anti-pattern

Comment: Fair enough, removed that from my answer.

Comment: This works, but the output returns 1 char under another. how to I get the whole word?

Comment: Are you saying you don't want a new line character printed after each item?

Comment: the result I am looking is "testdb1" so on. I can run os.popen command for each database. Like this  dbconn=os.popen(f"""db2 connect to {db_name}""").read()

Comment: Don't use edits to reply. I'm still confused as to what you're trying to do. Where did the spaces come from?

Comment: That I am not sure, I wish I could you show you an screen shot of output.

Comment: what is the exact copy-pasted output that you get? Wrap it in single tick marks: like this ` `this` `

Comment: Item returns this. ` T
E
S
T
D
B
1


T
E
S
T
D
B
2 ` Still can't past correct output here.

Comment: This is an entirely new question, and should be posted as such.

Answer (score 1):

First I would clarify your question, it seems like you want to print each item in a list of items.
2nd, I would create a reproducible example by creating your data structure.

```
db_name = ['testdb1','testdb2','testdb3','testdb4']
```

Then to print each element, you can do the pythonic way:

```
for db in db_name:
    print(db)
```

Or if you want to try using the i+=1 approach, you need to reference each element by it's position in the list:

```
i=0
while i < len(db_name):
    print(db_name[i])
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while i < len(db_name):
    print(db_name[i])
    i += 1
```

or even better

```
for i in range(0, len(db_name)):
    print(db_name[i])
```

and better yet

```
for name in db_name:
    print(name)
```

Comment: `range()` and `len()` in one expression is not beautiful. And you don't need any of them to iterate over a list.

Comment: how would you run os.popen command like this.  dbconn=os.popen(f"""db2 connect to {db_name}""").read()